# Load geoJSON file into Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I'm very new to this and learning as I go so please be patient!

I have a geoJSON file, which I have successfully (manually) imported into Mapbox / Leaflet.

However, rather than doing it manually, I would like to load the geojson file automatically. I have tried using the following code, where the file ('crimeReportSummary.geojson') is saved in the same directory as my Index.html file.

```
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.5/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.5/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<style>
  body { margin:0; padding:0; }
  #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='map'></div>
    <script>
    L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic3RldmVyZCIsImEiOiJ5T0hIMGU4In0.iRYeTkjtats3I4b2ZCBZVw';
    var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'steverd.l9nc6o7n')


    var featLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);
    featLayer.loadURL('crimeReportSummary.geojson'); 

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is, when I run this code, the map appears correctly, but none of the markers appear.

I would be **really** grateful if someone could advise me how to do this! I am a noob, so simple explanations are appreciated. I have spent hours today trying to figure this out, but without luck. Thanks so much in advance for your time.

Edit - the geoJSON file I'm using can be found [here](https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D2846470_87090753_407563)

Comment: Could you please add a sample of `crimeReportSummary.geojson` to your question?

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser Javascript console (hit F12)? Are you running this on a server or directly from the filesystem (file:// URL)? loadURL won't work from the filesystem.

Comment: Thanks all - IH8 please see link added to my main question. Jarek - yes, I am running this on a server. I will try the F12 test. Thanks both for your time.